# mysql error when adding function

Tags: mysql, replication, cumulative-sum

The following error is returned when trying to use a MySQL function..

```
#1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its
declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe 
log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

I couple of days ago I started using replication..? Don't know if this could have an incluence on it?! But I know one thing - it has worked :)

If I try to override (add the function again) the same error occurs..

The function

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `stock_in_stock_ids` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dynaccount`@`localhost` FUNCTION `stock_in_stock_ids`(_running_total_limit INT, _product_id INT, _group_id INT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _running_count INT default 0;
    DECLARE _id INT;
    DECLARE _count INT;
    DECLARE _ids TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE _cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, count FROM stock WHERE group_id=_group_id && type=2 && product_id=_product_id ORDER BY time DESC, id DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN _cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH _cur INTO _id, _count;

        IF done THEN
            SET _ids = '0';
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET _running_count = _running_count + _count;
        SET _ids = CONCAT_WS(',', _ids, _id);

        IF _running_count >= _running_total_limit THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE _cur;

    RETURN _ids;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here you have a post that saves me in the past about this error:
http://forum.9kgames.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=17

in my case I only had to specify the `DETERMINISTIC` in the create function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dynaccount`@`localhost` FUNCTION `stock_in_stock_ids`(_running_total_limit INT, _product_id INT, _group_id INT) 
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
```

hope it helps

**UPDATE: link is not working anymore so here is a copy from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20120310020353/http://forum.9kgames.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=17**

This warning is rising when

a). You want to create a stored function and 
b). As the default MySQL server supports replication, i.e, BINARY LOGGING is turned ON. 
To resolve this issue, there’re some tips here:

1). For stored function itself. When you create a stored function, you must declare either that it is deterministic or that it does not modify data. Otherwise, it may be unsafe for data recovery or replication. 
By default, for a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement to be accepted, at least one of `DETERMINISTIC`, `NO SQL`, or `READS SQL DATA` must be specified explicitly. Otherwise an error occurs: 
Code:

```
ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
(you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
variable).
```

This function is deterministic (and does not modify data), so it is safe: 
Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f1(i INT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  RETURN i;
END;
```

This function uses UUID() which is not deterministic, so the function also is not deterministic and is not safe: 
Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f2()
RETURNS CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8
BEGIN
  RETURN UUID();
END;
```

This function modifies data, so it may not be safe: 
Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f3(p_id INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  UPDATE t SET modtime = NOW() WHERE id = p_id;
  RETURN ROW_COUNT();
END;
```

MySQL does not check that a function declared DETERMINISTIC is free of statements that produce nondeterministic results. 
Although it is possible to create a deterministic stored function without specifying `DETERMINISTIC`, you cannot as of MySQL 5.1.15 execute this function using statement-based binary logging. To execute such a function, you must use row-based or mixed binary logging. Alternatively, if you explicitly specify DETERMINISTIC in the function definition, you can use any kind of logging, including statement-based logging.

2) Although you’ve finished the step 1, in most cases, you may still need SUPER privilege to set the global variable `log_bin_trust_function_creators` as true and then run to create stored function.
To relax the preceding conditions on function creation (that you must have the SUPER privilege and that a function must be declared deterministic or to not modify data), set the global `log_bin_trust_function_creators` system variable to 1. By default, this variable has a value of 0, but you can change it like this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

You can also set this variable by using the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` option when starting the server. 
If binary logging is not enabled, `log_bin_trust_function_creators` does not apply. SUPER is not required for function creation unless, as described previously, the DEFINER value in the function definition requires it. 
Note: If your applications run on a multi-tenant hosting server and the hosting company wouldn’t like to do this, you may need to modify your stored procedures instead of using stored functions.

Comment: Your link is not available anymore, makes your answer unusable.

Comment: @FlipVernooij the link is not working but the answer is there

Comment: true and it does answer the problem OP had, but for someone else having the same but slightly different problem (like me) the answer doesn't explain anything about the issue and so is useless for everyone else except OP.

Answer (score 4):

You should write the following lines between the "RETURNS TEXT" and "BEGIN". It will work.. :)

```
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, for a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement to be accepted, `at least one of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA` must be specified explicitly. Otherwise an error occurs:

ERROR 1418 (HY000): This routine has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
(you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_routine_creators
variable)

If you `set log_bin_trust_routine_creators to 1`, the requirement that routines be deterministic or not modify data is dropped.